# Creating multiple HTTP sections in Spring Security Java Config

Tags: java, spring-security, config

Using Spring Security XML configuration, you can define multiple HTTP elements to specify different access rules for different parts of your application. The example given in [8.6 Advanced Namespace Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/html/security-filter-chain.html#filter-chains-with-ns) defines separate stateful and stateless sections of the application, with the former using sessions and form login, and the latter using no sessions and BASIC authentication:

```
<!-- Stateless RESTful service using Basic authentication -->
<http pattern="/restful/**" create-session="stateless">
    <intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_REMOTE' />
    <http-basic />
</http>

<!-- Empty filter chain for the login page -->
<http pattern="/login.htm*" security="none"/>

<!-- Additional filter chain for normal users, matching all other requests -->
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_USER' />
    <form-login login-page='/login.htm' default-target-url="/home.htm"/>
    <logout />
</http>
```

I can't figure out how to do the same thing with Java Config. It's important that I disable sessions and use a different entry point for my web services. Right now I have the following:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity security)
{
    security.ignoring().antMatchers("/resource/**", "/favicon.ico");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception
{
    security
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?loginFailed")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/ticket/list")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
            .and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login?loggedOut")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
            .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionFixation().changeSessionId()
                .maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                .sessionRegistry(this.sessionRegistryImpl())
            .and().and().csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher((r) -> {
                    String m = r.getMethod();
                    return !r.getServletPath().startsWith("/services/") &&
                            ("POST".equals(m) || "PUT".equals(m) ||
                                    "DELETE".equals(m) || "PATCH".equals(m));
                });
}
```

Using this I was able to disable CSRF protection for my web services. But I really need a whole separate HTTP configuration so that I can disable sessions and specify a different entry point. I know I can use `requestMatcher` or `requestMatchers` to restrict the URIs that it applies to, but it doesn't appear that you can use this to create separate configurations. It's almost like I need *two* `configure(HttpSecurity security)` methods.

Comment: Create multiple classes for security configuration. The easiest is to create a general configuration with some internal `@Configuration` classes for configuring `HttpSecurity`.

Comment: Thanks. That was the answer. Also, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/test/groovy/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/SampleWebSecurityConfigurerAdapterTests.groovy#L277 shows an example of doing this with static inner classes. Can you put your comment in an answer so that I can mark it as the answer and give it an upvote?

Comment: The URL reference to the documentation (`8.6 Advanced Namespace Configuration`) is broken. Not you can find it here  http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-chains-with-ns

Comment: github link is also broken now. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/SampleWebSecurityConfigurerAdapterTests.java

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Spring Security to mimic the behavior of multiple `<http>` elements from XML in Java config create multiple classes for security configuration. In general it is the best/easiest to create a common security configuration with *multiple inner classes* for the security definition for `HttpSecurity`. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/905f30695ee61fd839e8519064ba1643258a2134/spring-security-javaconfig/src/test/groovy/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/SampleWebSecurityConfigurerAdapterTests.groovy#L274) for a sample.

And here the related section in the official Spring Security documentation:
[**5.7 Multiple HttpSecurity**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity)

Comment: I have followed the example here, but since second configuration is catch all, all the urls are getting intercepted by second config. As soon as I put in a specific url(through antMatcher) in second httpsecurity, all the urls are accessible without authentication.

Comment: The key to this answer is that each security configuration class must identify a unique URL path in the very first antMatcher().  Such as:
`protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.antMatcher("/secure**")`
alongside:
`protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.antMatcher("/api/**")`
The problem with the code in the issue is that this code matches ALL urls:
`security.authorizeRequests()`

Comment: @informatik01 when I click 'here' I get 404. Not sure what the reason is

Comment: @SandeepShukla The sampled moved tp another location in GitHub. I have updated the link to point to the current location, it is available now.