# How to require x509 Authentication for Spring OAuth Endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring 4.0 java configuration.

I want to require x509 auth on my oauth endpoints, but only require an oauth token for all other resource endpoints. The first `antMatchers` seems to be getting overridden:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  RequestMappingUriProvider requestMappingUriProvider;

  @Autowired
  private DelegatedUserManager userManager;

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    // @formatter:off
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    // @formatter:on
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    // Require x509 certificate for obtaining OAuth credentials
    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/**")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER","CLIENT")
        .and()
        .x509().subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?),").authenticationUserDetailsService(authenticationUserDetailsService())
        .and()
        //Only require a user role for interaction with all other resources
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers(requestMappingUriProvider.uriPatterns())
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER");
    // @formatter:on
  }

  @Bean
  public DelegatedAuthenticationUserDetailsService authenticationUserDetailsService() {
    return new DelegatedAuthenticationUserDetailsService(userManager);
  }

}
```

The debug output from spring doesn't show any of my `/oauth/**` endpoints being checked in the x509 filterchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that I needed multiple `HttpSecurity` elements. This post helped me: [Creating multiple HTTP sections in Spring Security Java Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815015/creating-multiple-http-sections-in-spring-security-java-config)

Here's how I implemented it:

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableResourceServer
  public static class ResourceServerConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class OAuthResourceServerConfigAdapter extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
      @Autowired
      private DelegatedUserManager userManager;

      @Override
      public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
      }

      @Override
      public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        // Require x509 certificate for obtaining OAuth credentials
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER","CLIENT")
            .and()
            .x509().subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?),").authenticationUserDetailsService(authenticationUserDetailsService());
        // @formatter:on
      }

      @Bean
      public DelegatedAuthenticationUserDetailsService authenticationUserDetailsService() {
        return new DelegatedAuthenticationUserDetailsService(userManager);
      }

    }

    public static class MyResourceServerConfigAdapter extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
      @Autowired
      RequestMappingUriProvider requestMappingUriProvider;

      @Override
      public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
      }

      @Override
      public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        //Only require a user role for interaction with all other resources
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers(requestMappingUriProvider.uriPatterns())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER");
        // @formatter:on
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: The general idea is correct (you need different filter chains for the two resource sets), but `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` is for configuring a Resource Server and the `/oauth/**` endpoints are part of the Authorization Server. It would actually be pretty unusual to protect the /token endpoint in the same way as the /authorize endpoint, but if you have what you need I guess that's just the way it is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For my purposes, I wanted to protect the Authorization endpoint as well as the Resources endpoints. So the user has to hit the authorize endpoint with their credentials and the client has to hit the token endpoint with their PKI credentials.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that. You want the resources to be protected by access tokens and x509 (as alternative authentication mechanisms)? In any case "/oauth/**" includes the authorization *and* token endpoints and it's quite unusual (unheard of) to secure those the same way.

Comment: My scenario works like this:
1. User goes to /oauth/authorize to get authorization code and instead of typing in a username and password, his PKI credentials authenticate him.
2. User is redirected to the client who receives the authorization code and sends a request to /oauth/token also via 2-way SSL so the client authenticates whith his PKI credentials (instead of basic auth) before receiving the access token.
3. Client can now use the access token until it expires.
I realize this is an unusual scenario.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Was wondering if this was possible myself.  Doesn't seem strange that you'd want to be able to use x509 to authenticate once and use tokens everywhere else instead of configuring the certs on every server.  Thanks for the post/research.