# Failed to configure both stateless and stateful http sections with Spring Security..?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to get both http-basic (stateless) and http with form-login to work together, but no luck so far. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815015/creating-multiple-http-sections-in-spring-security-java-config) what I'm trying to achieve seems possible. (Currently on Spring Security version 3.2.3). This is what I got:

```
<http pattern="/service/**" create-session="stateless">
    <intercept-url pattern="/test/**"   access="ROLE_TEST" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/remote/**" access="ROLE_REMOTE" />
    <http-basic />
</http>

<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/something/**"     access="ROLE_STH" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/somethignelse/**" access="ROLE_STHELSE" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**"               access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <form-login/>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authMgrDefault">
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service 
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username, password, is_enabled as enabled 
                                     from sys_user 
                                     where username = ?" 
            authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, r.authority 
                                           from sys_user u, sys_user_role r 
                                           where u.id = r.sys_user_id and u.username = ?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

With this configuration only the latter http seems to work (I get the login page). The first one seems to pass URLs freely without any authentication (as if anonymous).
What am I missing..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intercept-url pattern should be the entire path from the context root:

```xml
<http pattern="/service/**" create-session="stateless">
    <intercept-url pattern="/service/test/**"   access="ROLE_TEST" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/service/remote/**" access="ROLE_REMOTE" />
    <http-basic />
</http>
```