# Allowing a client application to configure http security from an already wired WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot and spring-security.

I have a generic `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` setup for a number of different projects.  The problem is that I want custom Controller security for each project, everything else remains the same.  The most obvious solution was to make it Abstract and force each project to extend it but I suspect there is a better way through events or something.

Here is the configure method of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    ...

    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/health*").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/endpoints/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/rest/open/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/login/impersonate*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "ADMINISTRATOR")

    // AT THIS POINT I WOULD LIKE EACH PROJECT TO OPTIONALLY CONFIGURE http AS THEY WISH

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();

    ...

}
```

Is there a cool way to do this in spring though a bean configuration or something?

```
@Bean //something like this perhaps????
public void configureSecurity(final HttpSecurity http) {
   http.authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/rest/admin*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "ADMINISTRATOR")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use multiple `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` classes, juste make sure each of them are in packages scanned by Springboot autoconfiguration.

if a client project want to override existing security constraints, add the `@Order` annotation:

```
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ClientSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
      public void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
            http.antMatcher("/rest/admin*").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "ADMINISTRATOR");
      }
}
```

Pay attention to the antMatcher() that is before the authorizeRequests(), this is done to limit the scope of the client config. without that, it will erase all of the default config (every URL except /rest/admin* will return 403 Unauthorized).

Comment: This didn't seem to work.  I can see both WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters being hit in debug mode but the one with `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` always looses out to  `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` and the security is not applied.

Comment: here's a similar question that might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815015/creating-multiple-http-sections-in-spring-security-java-config