# Spring security multiply HttpSecurity context and custom filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring security with multiply http security context.

Problem is that I can't made independent filter chain for each HttpSecurity context.
In each request (for /oldapi ot /newapi) both filters (oldDeviceApiAuthFilter and newApiDeviceAuthFilter) are called.

I need two *independent* filters:

- For /oldapi/** : only oldDeviceApiAuthFilter
- For /newapi/** : only newApiDeviceAuthFilter

So, is it possible?

**WebSecurityConfig.java:**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    // Device legacy API
    @Configuration
    @Order(30)
    public static class OldApiSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private final XmlRpcDeviceApiAuthFilter oldDeviceApiAuthFilter;
        @Autowired
        public OldApiSecurityConfigurationAdapter(XmlRpcDeviceApiAuthFilter oldDeviceApiAuthFilter) {
            this.oldDeviceApiAuthFilter = oldDeviceApiAuthFilter;
        }
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/oldapi/**")
                    .addFilterBefore(oldDeviceApiAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and().csrf().disable()
            ;
        }
    }

    // Device new API
    @Configuration
    @Order(40)
    public static class NewApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private final NewApiDeviceAuthFilter newApiDeviceAuthFilter;
        @Autowired
        public NewApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter(NewApiDeviceAuthFilter newApiDeviceAuthFilter) {
            this.newApiDeviceAuthFilter = newApiDeviceAuthFilter;
        }
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/newapi/**")
                    .addFilterBefore(newApiDeviceAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and().csrf().disable()
            ;
        }
    }

}
```

**Update:**

I see the next filter chain for requests to **/oldapi/** after I have enabled debug:

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  XmlRpcDeviceApiAuthFilter  <- ONLY ONE FILTER
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

But when I set breakpoint to my newApiDeviceAuthFilter I see that boths filters works on boths requests to **/oldapi/** and to **/newapi/**:

NewApiDeviceAuthFilter.java:

```
@Component
public class NewApiDeviceAuthFilter extends GenericFilterBean{

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Boolean myTest = true; // <-- BREAKPOINT HERE ALWAYS WORK
        chain.doFilter(request, response); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815015/creating-multiple-http-sections-in-spring-security-java-config

Comment: I have already done multiply configurations with multiply classes marked @Configuration.