# How do I add HTTP basic auth for a specific endpoint with spring security?

Tags: java, spring, http, security

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Security. A new endpoint `/health` is to be configured so it is accessible via basic HTTP authentication. The current `HttpSecurity` configuration is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http.requestMatchers()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
    .and()
    .csrf()
    .disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

}

How do I add base auth for `/health`? I figure I need something like this, but I don't think this is completely correct, and I don't really understand where exactly to add it:

```
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(
        // Health status
        "/health",
        "/health/"
    )
    .hasRole(HEALTH_CHECK_ROLE)
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .realmName(REALM_NAME)
    .authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint())
    .and()
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

I found these resources to be helpful, but not sufficient:

- http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication
- http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-basic-authentication/

Comment: did you try with `/health/**` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution is to implement multiple configurations, as explained here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity

EDIT 2021-12-11:

archive link of reference: https://web.archive.org/web/20210126145444/https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#multiple-httpsecurity

A similar question linking to an example is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18864786/1568224

Comment: link broken... please fix

Answer (score 5):

Using Spring Boot 3 with Spring Security 6:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/health/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .build();
}
```

This will authenticate only the endpoints under `/health` but leave all other endpoints exposed. You need to explicitly `permitAll()` on the endpoints not covered by security.

Comment: Thanks, I was about to go crazy trying to figure out why my Spring Security rules don'twork anymore after resolving all deprecations. Their documentation is useless.

Comment: Also, in case anyone else is doing the same as I and getting an error about "This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76809698/spring-security-method-cannot-decide-pattern-is-mvc-or-not-spring-boot-applicati

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
private BasicAuthEntryPoint basicAuthEntryPoint;

private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/",
        "/users/signup",
        "/reviews/create-review",
        "/auth/login",
        "/v3/api-docs/**",
        "/swagger-ui/**",
        "/products/**",
        "/docs/**",

};

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin(form -> form
            .loginPage("/auth/login"))
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic(httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer -> {
                httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer.authenticationEntryPoint(basicAuthEntryPoint);
            })
            // .exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(basicAuthEntryPoint)
            .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

    return http.build();
}
```