# why does spring security refuse to use my config file

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

im learning Spring security and created a config file to change the login from form to basic as a first step, however the config file doesn't do anything and no changes happen

here is the code in the config file:

```
package Security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class securityConfiguration {

@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity Sec ) throws Exception {
        Sec
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        return Sec.build();}



}
```

and this is my POM.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>test</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i suspected the problem might be spring not picking up the config file but the annotations did nothing to fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add HTTP basic auth for a specific endpoint with spring security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524211/how-do-i-add-http-basic-auth-for-a-specific-endpoint-with-spring-security)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue might have to do with how you are organizing the packages. By default, Spring will look under the package of the main application or any sub-packages.

It's hard to be sure from the information provided in the question, but for instance, if your main application class is under the package `com.example`, and the security configuration class is under the package `Security`, it won't find it by default. Also, be sure to not use the default package (or "no package").

So the options are:

- Add `@ComponentScan` annotation to the main class to indicate where to look: `@ComponentScan("Security")`
- Move the security config class under the same package as the main class or a sub-package: `com.example.security` (recommended).

See [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) for reference.

I also suggest that you use the standard naming and styling conventions for Java. (lower-case package names, lower-case method attributes, pascal-case class names). See [Naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) for reference. It will not only look better and consistent with other code bases but will also make it compatible with many tools that follow convention over configuration, which is favored a lot in the Spring ecosystem.

Comment: this worked, my package organization was a mess. thank you!