# Spring security method cannot decide pattern is MVC or not Spring Boot application exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, spring-security, backend

When I try to run an application it fails to start and throws this exception.

> This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC
> patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use
> requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use
> requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

I am new to Spring Security. Please help me solve this error.

This is my spring security configuration class

```java
package com.ronit.SpringSecurityTutorial.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authManager(UserDetailsService detailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoProvider.setUserDetailsService(detailsService);
        return new ProviderManager(daoProvider);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("removal")
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()).authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
            auth.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll();
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        }).httpBasic().and().build();
    }
}
```

This is the spring boot application

```java
package com.ronit.SpringSecurityTutorial;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import com.ronit.SpringSecurityTutorial.models.ApplicationUser;
import com.ronit.SpringSecurityTutorial.models.Role;
import com.ronit.SpringSecurityTutorial.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.ronit.SpringSecurityTutorial.repository.UserRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSecurityTutorialApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityTutorialApplication.class,args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner run(RoleRepository roleRepository, UserRepository userRepository,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        return args -> {
            if (roleRepository.findByAuthority("ADMIN").isPresent())
                return;
            Role adminRole = roleRepository.save(new Role("ADMIN"));
            roleRepository.save(new Role("USER"));

            Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
            roles.add(adminRole);
            ApplicationUser admin = new 
            ApplicationUser(1, "Admin", passwordEncoder.encode("Password"), roles);
            userRepository.save(admin);
        };
    }
}
```

These are the dependencies in pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

There is no configuration related to security in application.properties file.

I searched this on Google and found some Stack Overflow pages, but none of them were using similar configuration to mine.

I have watched an online tutorial and made this. I followed each step correctly, but my configuration is not working.

The application is stopped and terminated straight away.

I am using Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security 6 in my application.

Comment: I am using a youtube tutorial to learn spring security.  If anyone could tell me about other resources to stay updated with the latest version of spring security it would be  appreciable thanks for reading my question

Comment: I am unable to understand what are mvc and non-mvc patterns if anyone could explain it to me it would be a great  deal

Comment: Thank you for editing James it would be better if you could provide some help

Comment: this solves your problem https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34035

Comment: @Toerktumlare is correct but the answer can be elaborated more

Comment: One thing that is wrong with your configuration is that you have `auth.anyRequest().authenticated();` twice. Basically the first one already renders everything after that useless. This line has to come last not as the first, as the rules are consulted in the order they are defined in .

Answer (score 30):

A migration occurred due to vulnerability [CVE-2023-34035](https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34035).

In the event that you get an error like the following:

> This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC
> patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use
> `requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher)`; otherwise, please use
> `requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher)`.

You should use **a complete RequestMatcher**.

For example, if an application has a servlet deployed to /my-servlet/* and is authorizing that traffic like so:

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain appSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/my-servlet/**").hasRole("USER")
            .requestMatchers("/spring-mvc-controller/**").hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        // ...
    return http.build();
}
```

then, the application should instead do the following:

```
import static org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher;

@Bean
MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc(HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) {
    return new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
}

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain appSecurity(HttpSecurity http, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/my-servlet/*")).hasRole("USER")
            .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/spring-mvc-controller/**")).hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        // ...
    return http.build();
}
```

For more details read this repository offered by Spring: [cve-2023-34035-mitigations](https://github.com/jzheaux/cve-2023-34035-mitigations)

Comment: Excellent post - I still don't understand how the docu hasn't been updated in that regard.

Answer (score 14):

For now there are two options recommended by https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34035

**First Option:**
Did a small very simple poc war web application in tomcat.
Debugged  this method -

org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers(HttpMethod method, String... patterns)

Studied https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34035

Just before the below lines in above mentioned method I examined what was in the registrations object.

Assert.isTrue(registrations.size() == 1, "This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).");

Found it to be registrations of

```
org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet against "default"
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet against "jsp"
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet against "dispatcher"
```

In https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34035 they mention
"Sometimes these extra servlets are not needed. For example, some servlet containers will add a DefaultServlet that DispatcherServlet effectively replaces. In many cases, such a servlet can be removed from your container's global configuration".

What they are saying is that we should edit apache-tomcat-10.1.10\conf\web.xml.

We should comment out the registrations in that web.xml for org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet,
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.
We should also remove the mapping entries in same web.xml

For other servlet containers we can consider similar concepts.

**Second Option:**
The other option is to do what they also suggested in "For an example mitigation, please see the following Spring Security sample application and the corresponding diff." https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34035 namely follow https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/commit/4e3bec904a5467db28ea33e25ac9d90524b53d66

In other words the example they give is
Replace :

```
    .requestMatchers("/login", "/resources/**").permitAll()
```

with

```
    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/login"),
         mvc.pattern("/resources/**")).permitAll()
```

In a web application you would usually use mvc matcher as shown here.
You can also use ant matcher - there is a little risk in using ant matchers as explained here- [Difference between antMatcher and mvcMatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536292/difference-between-antmatcher-and-mvcmatcher) . **Using ant matcher is best avoided unless you are willing to do necessary testing if you start using it.** In complex scenarios can use regexmatchers also - use it only if needed (not in this scenario where you just want to solve this current issue).

Regarding how to achieve mvc.pattern() itself here are the steps.  Declare a bean as below somewhere.

```
@Bean
    MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc(HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) {
        return new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
    }
```

In your security configurations just autowire it like so:

```
@Autowired
    MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc;
```

**Decision Point:**

If you want to retain original code try editing the server's (not project's) web.xml-or similar configuration if not tomcat - but some other servlet container , to eliminate the extra servlets that come by default in servlet containers.
If you are willing to change code try the second option.

*Also Note:*

Sometimes if its legacy code and you are using DispatcherServlet methods in your code you will have to eliminate that to use first option or else settle for second option.

Hope this helps

**Adding more new information**:

In fact if you further migrate from spring-boot-starter-parent:3.1.2 to spring-boot-starter-parent:3.1.3 the messages are even clearer.
It says the problem:
there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet=[*.jspx, *.jsp], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.

And that is why following https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34035 one option is to just disable the default and jsp related servlets. Useful if you dont want to change code but are fine with changing server configuration.

The second option if you go the code change route was always clearly logged.
"For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path." Only as "otherwise" they mention AntMatchers

I will repeat avoid AntMatcher because of its dangers when using web applications for this migration purpose if you go for second option.

Comment: But how do I use it with Vaadin? I only have WebSecurity

Comment: @ChristophS haven't used Vaadin in a long while. Are you saying you faced the same issue in Vaadin recently? This is a recent spring boot latest issue. Where you using spring with Vaadin?

Comment: Yes, I am using Vaadin with Spring Boot, upgraded to spring boot 3.1.2 and got this issue with the overriden webSecurity, but cannot change to mvc matcher
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security 
with 
web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/actuator/health/**");

Comment: @ChristophS . Sorry for delay. Can u share some sample code on a git repository. I do believe the answer lies in the steps I shared. That said if you share your code as a sample I could have a look and try to give you more specific suggestions.

Comment: I looked into the Vaadin sources and they used an AntPathRequestMatcher for the ignoring parts. So I used this as well and it works.

Comment: @ChristophS That's the second option I indicated wherein you have to change existing code. You could also use mvcMatcher. First option is useful if you want to try achieving same without changing code but rather change the server configurations. Use either based on your convenience. I just provided both solutions so that its a complete picture.

Comment: @ChristophS One more thing. Do test the security expressions and the results thoroughly because you chose the second option. I believe this was resolving to mvcmatcher before this issue. In the past there have been known subtle differences in how ant mactchers and mvcmatchers work. If you chose the code change route and went for AntMatcher do test the actual security especially about whether the actual url has or has not a trailing /.

Comment: @CristophS Please refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536292/difference-between-antmatcher-and-mvcmatcher . Not sure if this is still valid or not. But do test ur fix more thoroughly because you chsoe the code change option and went for AntMatcher instead of mvcMatcher. Hope you find this tip helpful

Comment: Yes, did a test. Works all. This was the only place where I needed this change, it configures the ignoring for my health check endpoint.

Comment: @ChristophS Noted. Anyone else reading this- prefer mvc matcher or the 1st option. You would not have had that deviaton for some urls as faced by ChristphS for his  health check endpoint. Generally for web projects prefer mvc matcher. Ant matcher is basically needed when u dont have mvc or web concepts in your spring application. No harm in using it. Just use it with care if you use it.

Comment: as explained here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536292/difference-between-antmatcher-and-mvcmatcher and also in the previous edition of Spring Security in Action book be very careful when using AntMatchers

Comment: Changing the web.xml inside tomcat conf folder did it for me. Big thanks!

Comment: @Splekke Glad it worked for you. I just wish readers realized there are two ways to solve this and see the pros and cons of each approach and take a studied approach. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is small configuration which will prevent us from:

```
This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).
```

error.
It is clearly mentoined at [Configuration Migrations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html)

> If you are having problem with the new `requestMatchers` methods, you can always switch back to the `RequestMatcher` implementation that you were using. For example, if you still want to use `AntPathRequestMatcher` and `RegexRequestMatcher` implementations, you can use the `requestMatchers` method that accepts a `RequestMatcher` instance:

Okay! In the context of your issue mentoined in the code above you should try to add `antMatcher(pattern)` as parameter to `requestMatchers()` as shown below:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
           .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
            auth.requestMatchers(antMatcher("/auth/**")).permitAll();
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        }).httpBasic().and().build();
    }
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve the ambiguity by wrapping the string patterns with matchers.

Before:

```
http
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/dashboard/run/**").authenticated()
        .requestMatchers("/editor/**").authenticated()
        .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
```

After:

```
http
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/dashboard/run/**")).authenticated()
        .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/editor/**")).authenticated()
        .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/**")).permitAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

The above issue was resolved with the below method:

```
String[] unSecuredPaths = new String[]{
            "/validate",
            "/"}

    private AntPathRequestMatcher[] getAntPathRequestMatchers() {
            AntPathRequestMatcher[] requestMatchers = new AntPathRequestMatcher[unSecuredPaths.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < unSecuredPaths.length; i++) {
                requestMatchers[i] = new AntPathRequestMatcher(unSecuredPaths[i]);
            }
            return requestMatchers;
        }
    
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        contentSecurityConfig(http);

        AntPathRequestMatcher[] requestMatchers = getAntPathRequestMatchers();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(**requestMatchers**).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()).httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

For MvcRequestMatcher, replace AntPathRequestMatcher with MvcRequestMatcher, exact solutions should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems when trying to setup OAuth2 resource server. I was using h2 for my REST data store. So it was complaining

> there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context:
> {org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet=[/h2-console/*],
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.

Below is the config I used to solve it. Ignore the OAuth2 parts in the code. Hope this helps.

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers(antMatcher(("/h2-console/**")))
                                .permitAll()

                                .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/posts"), antMatcher(HttpMethod.POST))
                                .hasAuthority("SCOPE_createBlogPost")

                                .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/posts"), antMatcher(HttpMethod.DELETE))
                                .hasAuthority("SCOPE_deleteBlogPost")

                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated())
                .headers(headersConfigurer -> headersConfigurer.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
                .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.ignoringRequestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**")))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer ->
                        oAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.jwt(withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not.

If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use `requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher)`; otherwise, please use `requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher)`.

My usage as below:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**")))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions().sameOrigin())
            .formLogin(withDefaults())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when using spring security with h2 database. I tried to disable the h2-console, or switch to MySQL, the error is gone.

So I think this error is related to h2 database, currently I don't have any solution for this h2 database. I'm using MySQL instead