# Spring Security: Creating multiple http-sections dynamically

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Currently, I'm trying to figure out how to block every request, except for some routes secured with basic auth. 
The information of these routes is stored in a `List` of my utility object `SecurityConstraintInfo` (read from some configuration-file), which holds the username/password for the basic auth, needed a role and the protected url-pattern.

So far I was able to configure the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`, but my attempts to configure the `HttpSecurity`-parts failed miserably. 
For example, gives me the call with **user a** with a restricted path for **user b** a http-status-code 200. Example call with `cURL`:
curl -v --user a:a http://localhost:8080/b/xxx

I guess the way to go is [**5.9 Multiple HttpSecurity**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity) mentioned in [Creating multiple HTTP sections in Spring Security Java Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815015/creating-multiple-http-sections-in-spring-security-java-config/18864786#18864786).

How can I dynamically register the http-sections? It should be doable some way since Spring Security configuration via XML must configure the `<http>` elements dynamically one way or the other.

Security-Config:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private final List<SecurityConstraintInfo> securityConstraints = Arrays
      .asList(new SecurityConstraintInfo("a", "a", "a", "a/**"), new SecurityConstraintInfo("b", "b", "b", "b/**"));

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    for (final SecurityConstraintInfo securityConstraintInfo : securityConstraints) {
      http.authorizeRequests() //
          .antMatchers(securityConstraintInfo.getUrlPattern()) //
          .hasRole(securityConstraintInfo.getRolename()) //
          .and() //
          .httpBasic();
    }
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    final InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> inMemoryAuthentication =
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
    inMemoryAuthentication.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    for (final SecurityConstraintInfo securityConstraintInfo : securityConstraints) {
      inMemoryAuthentication.withUser(securityConstraintInfo.getUsername())
          .password(securityConstraintInfo.getPassword()).roles(securityConstraintInfo.getRolename());
    }
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
  }

  public class SecurityConstraintInfo {
    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String rolename;

    private String urlPattern;

    public SecurityConstraintInfo(final String username, final String password, final String rolename,
        final String urlPattern) {
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
      this.rolename = rolename;
      this.urlPattern = urlPattern;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
      return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(final String username) {
      this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
      return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(final String password) {
      this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRolename() {
      return rolename;
    }

    public void setRolename(final String rolename) {
      this.rolename = rolename;
    }

    public String getUrlPattern() {
      return urlPattern;
    }

    public void setUrlPattern(final String urlPattern) {
      this.urlPattern = urlPattern;
    }

  }

}
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("a/*")
    public String callA() {
        return "a";
    }

    @GetMapping("b/*")
    public String callB() {
        return "b";
    }

}
```

Startup:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M7</version>
        <relativePath /> 
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: *http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();*  should be `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().denyAll();`

Comment: Thanks for your patience. `denyAll()` unfortunately returns http-status-code 403 for all requests.

Comment: Did you replace it at the same (last) position? Your other rules should apply first. But I see your rules (`"a", "a", "a", "a/**"`)  are wrong. These URLs are not absolute.

Comment: Thanks a million. My erroneous URLs were also part of the problem. The URLs and denyAll() is the accepted answer.