# Can not bypass basic authentication for /swagger-ui/index.html

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, openapi

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.2 Security with following config for my open-api's swagger and other end points. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815015/creating-multiple-http-sections-in-spring-security-java-config/18864786#18864786) and a lots of other related SO threads.

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain filterChainSwaggerUI(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll();
    return http.build();
}
```

I tried to combine them into one Bean and I tried without order as well. But every time I hit  `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html` I see the login pop up in the browser. Which I dont want. I need the auth pop-up for my rest of the other end points only.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between the `antMatchers` in `authorizeRequests` and `antMatchers` for `HttpSecurity`. If you change it to the following, it should work:

```java
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain filterChainSwaggerUI(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/swagger-ui/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    return http.build();
}
```

Notice that I used `http.antMatcher` in the first bean.

With this configuration, you are saying that the first `SecurityFilterChain` will only apply to requests that start with `/swagger-ui`, and that every request that comes in is permitted. The second `SecurityFilterChain` will apply to any other request. Remember that only one `SecurityFilterChain` will be applied to the request.

You could also do it with one bean:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatcher("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .httpBasic();
    return http.build();
}
```

There is a simple repository that configures Spring Security to allow requests to `/swagger-ui/**`, you can run the `SpringSecurityAllowSwaggerApplicationTests` tests to see the behavior. https://github.com/marcusdacoregio/spring-security-allow-swagger-url

Comment: I tried both but did not work. No luck. You might wanna change `antMatcher` to `antMatchers` .

Comment: configuration in this answer is correct, maybe something else is wrong，you can set logging level of package `org.springframework.security` to `debug` and show us the log

Comment: I've updated my answer with a sample repository